# Tim lies a lot, so should we believe Tim is the King of France when he claims he isn't?

Tags: belief

Tim lies a lot, so should we believe Tim is the King of France when he claims he isn't? What fallacy is saying we should? Is the testimony of a proven liar sometimes or never reason to believe the opposite of what they say?

Comment: interesting to hear from any poker players ha. i think that if you suspect a lie/bluff then MAYBE you just ignore it and play the hand you otherwise think they have. but i'm not sure... double bluffs etc

Comment: The answer depends on context which is entirely missing. One can believe even liars when they make [statements against interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_against_interest), for example.

Comment: so it's not a fallacy @Conifold ? idt the fact a liar says something should count against it... sounds like bs to me, but yeah

Comment: Alas, we cannot ask Tim yes/no questions to find the answers to all questions in science, business, and religion by binary search.

Comment: @Conifold Despite certain legal presumptions, people falsely make statements against interest all the time. Sometimes it is deliberate because they think they are protecting someone or something else. Sometimes it is unintentional because they were simply mistaken when they make the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People can lie by saying something they believe (or even know) to be true, with the expectation that something about the context in which it is said, or the way it's said, will motivate the audience to disbelieve. (We have this word "mendacity" which offhand seems to be just a fancy way to say "dishonest" but which carries some of the tone of "insincere," and might be adapted to this deceptive-truthfulness case; that's more or less how "mendacity" was used in [a certain fantasy series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Thomas_Covenant), anyway.) Perhaps Tim, for example, knows he has a reputation for saying false things, and floats a certain claim out of some tortuous wish to trick the people he's making this claim in front of, into adopting a preposterous belief about him.

We could go on to try to come up with a taxonomy of deceptive/related (speech) acts (the SEP article about the topic [mentions something about wearing a wedding ring, for example, when one is unmarried; or taking the ring off when one *is* married](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lying-definition/#StaCon); or we might wear a ring that seems like a wedding ring but which is something else (even a purity ring, say) and yet the wearer recognizes that most people will "jump to conclusions" about what the ring symbolizes), although when I just tried to do so, I lost my train of thought after the sixth listing. C.f., though, phrases like, "I know that you know," and how in some stories, they turn that phrase [into a puzzle of confrontation](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IKnowYouKnowIKnow).

Comment: if we can exclude these mendacities, does the testimony of a liar count as evidence against something?

Answer (score 4):

First, I am not the king of France, but I also do not lie a lot.

More seriously, the answer is simply no under any set of assumptions that are remotely close to the real world.

If we have some sort of hypothetical where we know someone **always** lies **and** we define "lie" in a narrow way, then we can naturally conclude that any statement made by that person is false and that the negation must be true. However, such a situation exists only in logic puzzles and fantasies such as the [Labyrinth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labyrinth_(1986_film)).

In assumption sets anywhere close to the real world, then the fact someone says something is simply evidence that it may be true and if it is in a situation where we really care about the truth (such as say a trial), then we should further interrogate the statement to consider it. The credibility of the person making the statement is definitely a major factor in that. We should not automatically assume that even the most honest person in the world is always telling the truth because they may have made a mistake or simply been deceived themselves. Instead, we would look at other evidence to see if it is at least consistent with the claim. We would consider how likely it is that the person speaking may have misremembered or been mistaken.

When someone is known to lie frequently, we would simply assign little evidentiary weight to statements they made. Without more, we would not be inclined to believe a statement made by such a person. But we would never be justified in concluding that something was automatically true just because a known liar said the opposite of it.

Comment: In addition, liars from logic puzzles always lie, just for the sake of saying the opposite of the truth, but frequent liars from the real world tend to lie only "in one particular direction", for instance Alice will lie to embellish her own accomplishments, and Bob will lie to paint himself as an unlucky victim of circumstances; and the boy who cries Wolf will cry Wolf. Since random events from real life are not all aligned in one particular direction, the truth is bound to overlap sometimes with a liar's favoured direction, and the boy who cries Wolf will not lie when there really is a wolf.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the [base rate fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_rate_fallacy).

If you ask everyone in the world "are you the Emperor of Japan" and 99% of them answer truthfully, then even though only 1% of the answers will be lies, 99.999...% of the "yes" answers will be lies, because the fraction of people who lie is much larger than the fraction of people who are the Emperor of Japan.

To turn this into your problem, negate everything (99% chance of lying), reduce the number of people you ask to 1 (which doesn't change the probabilities), and replace the Emperor of Japan (who exists) with the King of France (who doesn't).

Comment: 99.99999875% of the "yes" answers will be lies ;-p